# How to login to the website using JSoup and retrieve user data

Tags: java, jsoup

So, I have a website. I know, that when you enter the user data - it sends a POST request. Let's say it makes a request to a http://website.com/e/auth?login=student-login&pass=student-pass
As a response, I get a JS code - which will redirect me (using document.location.href='mainpage?s_id=student-id-hashed&s_h=student-pass-hashed') and will alert me, if user data is wrong.
The data I need is located at http://website.com/e/data
How can I get the data? I know that you can make a Connection.Response object (connecting to an URL and executing) and get cookies. After this, you can pass cookies and get Document object. My problem is that I don't get any cookies. Can someone give me the example of the code that gets the Document with needed data?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly, but you won't be able to login using JSoup. Because, as you said, it's done by sending a POST request and *hopefully* not by passing the password in the URL like in your example. Anyway, I know this is only partly helpful.

Comment: @mumpitz well, you can send a POST without passing the password in the URL via JSoup. And I solved the problem (it's possible to get the info using JSoup), but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @RustemGaliev Please post your solution as an answer to this question, it would be helpful to others.  You can accept your own answer after a period of time (I think 24 hours but I'm not certain). Thank you!